# JQuery List function with button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I´ve got the following JQuery function:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($) {
    $.fn.addToList = function(opts) {
        var input = this;
        opts.button.click(function() {
            opts.list.append("<li>" + input.val() + "</li>");
        });
    }
})

$("#example").addToList({
    button: $("#btn"),
    list: $("#list")
});
</script>
```

with this html input field:

```
<input type="text" id="example">
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click">
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

What I want to do with that is, to type in a value in the input file, press on the button and the value is added to a ul-list. 
Unfortunately, the code above doesn´t work. In `jsfiddle` it worked.

Does anybody see a mistake in my code?

**EDIT:** Does anybody know a completed JQuery-example that has the same functionality?

Comment: Did you include jQuery correctly?

Answer (score 4):

You're not passing jQuery in as your `$` parameter.

Try the following:

```
 (function($) {
  $.fn.addToList = function(opts) {
    var input = $(this);
    opts.button.click(function() {
        opts.list.append("<li>" + input.val() + "</li>");
    });
  }
}(window.jQuery))
```

Comment: unfortunately, it still doesn´t work. Do you know why my input field automatically gets a textarea instead a textfield?

Comment: @user896692 Answer updated. As to why `#example` is a `textarea` rather than `input[type="text"]` I could only guess that another bit of javascript has changed the DOM, there is nothing in what you have posted that would cause this.

Comment: Ok, I solved the textarea thing, you were right about the DOM. But the function still does not work. Maybe you can look at this: [link] http://jsfiddle.net/2EFTZ/3/

Comment: @user896692 Your javascript was invalid. The jslint validation feature of jsfiddle is very useful at spotting this. See http://jsfiddle.net/2EFTZ/4/ for update.

Comment: Yeah ok, for sure. Now it works... But if I write it in my header.php, it does not work. How can I figure out where the problem is?

Comment: @user896692 Use a javascript debugger, Chrome has one built in (press F12), Firefox has many useful plugins (I recommend firebug) and IE has developer tools (press F12). Any of these should help you debug your script to figure out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Write

```
    jQuery(function($){ ...
```

instead of just

```
    function($) ...
```